# Thesis 2.1.2 - Translation - missing parts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

i downloaded a translation for the Thesis 2.1.2 wordpress theme, but not all content is translated. I have a Problem with:

- The main page where all posts are listed still shows "10 comments" and not the translation.
- Each post shows "by authorname on date" - which is not translated
- And on the single page of a post in the bottom before the textarea it states "Comment" and in the footer it shows "Previous post:" and "Next post:" ...

Does somebody know in which files these words are listed, so that I can change this directly in the code? Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The text snippets you have quoted seen to belong to the core Wordpress installation. You need to find and upload .mo file(s) for your language(s) to your wp-content/languages folder.

For more details on finding language files, see http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language, and for information on installing them, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language.

To switch between languages you may want to use the qtranslate plugin, for example. You will find it in the plugin repository.

Hope this will help!